# Move image between points

Tags: javascript, css

I want to move this image on click event. With only the javascript it simply appears at the click location without a transition.

```
<body>
    <img id="player" src = "images/man.png"></img>

<script>
    var x_click;
    var y_click;
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    document.addEventListener("click", move_player)

    function move_player(e) {
        x_click = e.clientX;
        y_click = e.clientY;

        player.style.left = x_click - player.clientWidth/2 + "px";
        player.style.top = y_click - player.clientHeight/2 + "px";  
    }


</script>
</body>
```

I've made a transition in CSS:

```
position:relative;
transition: left .5s linear, top .5s linear;
```

However, the speed is the same. If I want to move the image 300px, it takes 0.5 seconds, if I want to move it 1000px it also takes 0.5 seconds. I'm looking for a way to move it at a certain speed: If it takes 0.5 seconds for 300px, then for 1000 it should take 1.5-1.6s. How can I achieve this in Javascript? I'm not using any libraries such as JQuery etc.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle so we can test the code for you

Comment: Yes..You can achieve this using javascript..You can simply manipulate the values of transition considering the difference..
You can achieve this using core JS..

Comment: @Rayon Dabre can you post a link to such tutorial? ty

Comment: Set player.style.transition (or player.style.transitionDuration i think) before you set the new position

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('your_id').style.animationDuration="1s";
```

For cross browser:
Try something like this with specific prefix:

```
document.getElementById('your_id').style.webkitTransitionDuration="1s";
```

Comment: It still takes the same amount of time to move from A to B. It doens't matter how close or how far they are.

Comment: @Shury, there must be some criteria to know how much distance is among the objects. According to that you need to change the duration..

Comment: I used the formula for distance bettween two points:`var dist = Math.sqrt((parseInt(x_click)-parseInt(player.style.left))*(parseInt(x_click)-parseInt(player.style.left))+
  parseInt((y_click)-parseInt(player.style.top))*(parseInt(y_click)-parseInt(player.style.top)));
  alert(dist);
  player.style.animationDuration= parseInt(dist/100) + "s";` At click event I enter the move function above and try to change the player.style.animationDuration with the value above, but it's not working, Should the CSS be modified in some way?

Comment: @Shury, You need to debug things..I think you are almost there..Just little more debugging and conditions...